# It's correct to say that $\log _{ 1 }{ 1 } =1\quad $ & $0$?

Tags: logarithms

$\log _{ 1 }{ 1 } =1\quad $ v $0$?

Because $1^1 = 1$ and $1^0 = 1$?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Probably yes...

Comment: By that line of reasoning $\log_1 1 = $ anything at all, since $1^x = 1$ for any $x$...

Comment: That is right. All complex numbers are a logarithm of $1$ to the base $1$, since for each complex number $c$, $1$ is one of the $c$th powers of 1. 

I do not know if this is true for all quaternions or octonions.

Answer (score 9):

There's no such thing as base-$1$ logarithms (because $x\mapsto 1^x$ is not injective, if you want a concrete reason), so claiming *anything* about it is incorrect.

Comment: I know that log_a (b) exists only (in R) if a&b>0 and a =/= 1 but im curious why it ain't true if def. clearly says that log_a(b) = c <==> a^x = b (sorry if u cannot understand me properly...)

Comment: @Xiaox: If you have a source that claims that to be the definition without requiring that $a\ne 1$, then that's a source that peddles bad definitions, and you should treat what it says with skepticism.

Comment: The definition that I know requires a ≠ 1, but as I said before I'm curious why there isn't log_1 (1) if log_a(b) = c <==> a^x = b

Comment: @Xiaox: That definition _will not work_ for $a=1$, because a definition of a function is supposed to define _one and only one_ function value for each argument -- but since $1=1^0=1^1=1^2=1^{-42}=1^\pi=\cdots$ there are a lot of different values that your attempted definition _all_ claim equal $\log_1(1)$. But it's implicit in the use of function notation the $\log_1(1)$ should denote only one number (well, _at most one_ number, because it actuall denotes no number at all) -- so a "definition" that would lead it to equal everything actually fails to define anything at all.

Comment: Well, thanks. PS: It may be considered as exception?